# View getting null in onActivityResult()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I am trying to get barcode scanning results, but sometimes `textview` is getting `null`. Is scanning results getting before fragment is loaded or any another issue?

The following is my crash report:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.infinity.ilfms/com.example.infinity.ilfms.views.material_collected.MaterialCollectedActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=135123, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.infinity.ilfms/com.example.infinity.ilfms.views.material_collected.MaterialCollectedActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3325)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2635)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5736)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:910)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=135123, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.infinity.ilfms/com.example.infinity.ilfms.views.material_collected.MaterialCollectedActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3925)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3276)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3325)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2635)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5736)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:910)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
       at com.example.infinity.ilfms.views.material_collected.MaterialCollectedFragment.refreshViewOnSuccessIfAnyForOthers(MaterialCollectedFragment.java:373)
       at com.example.infinity.ilfms.views.base_view.fragements.BaseFragment.onActivityResult(BaseFragment.java:134)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6475)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3921)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3276)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3325)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2635)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5736)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:910)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
```

Here is my onActivityResult():

```
@Override
    protected void refreshViewOnSuccessIfAnyForOthers(int requestCode, int typeOfImage, Intent data, int resultCode) {
        super.refreshViewOnSuccessIfAnyForOthers(requestCode, typeOfImage, data, resultCode);

        if (requestCode == 4051) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //get the extras that are returned from the intent
                String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                Logger.logError(LOG_TAG,"Barcode result "+contents);
                String format = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                if(etRouterCode!=null) {
                    etRouterCode.setText(contents);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: How does your `onActivityResult` look like?

Comment: Post your activity code please

Comment: @MuratK.  I posted my activity code

Comment: @RobertEstivill I posted acivity code

Comment: Post all the activity. Obviously the problem is not in that method, but how you are initialising etRouterCode

Comment: `etRouterCode` is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for the same. Here when I recreating fragment after capturing a barcode, fragment receives a data before the view is created.
That's why the application was crashing.